# With a Node.js cluster, how do I share connections?

Tags: node.js, iisnode

I have an Azure hosted application (iisnode) that accepts direct connections from multiple client services. This application streams data between the various connections. If running on a system with multiple instances of node.js, the actual TCP connections will be connecting to different instances.

Is there a way to somehow "move" or "share" the in-memory connection from one instance to another?

Sure, I could build some inter-instance communication to route data, but I don't think the application will scale since it's entire purpose is to move data around quickly. For example, I would have 4 instances, 100 connections to each, and I would spend as many resources moving the data between instances as I would spend moving the data between the client connections.

Comment: Are you referring to the socket connections? What is your actual purpose with this?

Comment: It's a fairly complex proxy.

Answer (score 2):

When you configure iisnode to create more than one node.exe process (using the nodeProcessCountPerApplication setting), it will dispatch incoming HTTP requests between them using a round robin logic; the application has no control over that behavior. Given your scenario there is no way to deterministically ensure that the requests ("connections") from two distinct clients will be colocated in the same node.exe process.

There is no mechanism to "move" an existing TCP connection or HTTP request between node.exe processes.

In general a better way to address such a notification scenario may be to use a subscription-based messaging infrastructure as your backend. ServiceBus in Azure provides such mechanisms. In this design, each instance of node.exe would subscribe to a particular topic when it receives a connection from the client, and be notified by ServiceBus when a matching notification arrives, possibly via a different instance of node.exe.